# Normalising image album database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-normalization

[image: First version]

Above is my normalised database structure for my app. I am going to store Users, and their favorited Images. Images might be alone (hosted on reddit) or in albums (hosted on imgur), and they always have a title.

Question is - is the database set up correctly? I have this feeling that i have something wrong with ImageAlbum and Image table relationship.

EDIT: This might work?
[image]

Comment: The model above seems to miss that a user can own a single image (hosted on reddit). The way your datamodel looks now, it implies an image is always hosted in an album, and there is no direct way for a user to own a single image. I would normally set something like this up by having a user, image and album tables, and a bunch of tables establishing the many-to-many relationships. I.e. UserImage to determine the links between images and users (An image can be favorited by multiple users, and a user can favorite one or more images (or none)). Do the same for Image and Album.

Comment: I made the table as you described, would that work?

Comment: second image looks much better.. but no need to pull out the title - seems like overkill

Comment: Yeah, I started DB course this semester, so we are drilled with those normalization rules and what not. Thanks for feedback! Where can i accept an answer on a comment?

Comment: You can't. I'll add my comment as an answer, though :)

Comment: What do you mean, "normalized"? The term without a particular NF means nothing unless you mean to 1NF, in which case there is no standard specific meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the original design is that the intended relationship between a user and an image would not be possible, as the two tables are not connected.

As a general rule of thumb, if there's a 1-1 or a 1-many relationship between tables, you can rely on constraints. I.e. 1 customer can place many orders. You have a `Customer` table with a `CustomerID` PK column, and an `Order` table containing an `OrderID` PK column, and a Foreign Key constraint to the `CustomerID` column of the Customer table. That establishes the relationship, and ensures that you cannot place an order if you are not a customer.

An order typically consists of one or more products, and a product typically can be purchases in multiple orders. In cases like this, you cannot set up this relationship the same way. A common workaround for that is to do so using an intermediate table that establishes the many-to-many relationship.

So building on the earlier tables, we also have a `Product` table, with a `ProductID` column as a PK. To set up the relationship between `Order` and `Product`, you would then credit an `OrderProduct` table, with FKs pointing to the `OrderID` and `ProductID` in question (and probably also something indicating quantity of products for this particular order, and perhaps something like a FK to a Discount or campaign table, and whatnot).

So in your scenario, I would establish the relationship between `Image` and `User` using a similar approach, and simply adding a `UserImage` table to allow for the many-to-many relationship. You then also add an AlbumImage table to determine the many-to-many relationship between images and albums.

As indicated in the comments, there's no need to have an AlbumTitle table, really. It would naturally belong to the Album table. The ImageTitle would belong in the UserImage table, because every user can add their own title to an image.